# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "20-MAR-17 08.30.41.453267 AM"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to copy data spooled form oracle to PostgreSQL with csv format.
I am getting below error while doing  the copy .

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "20-MAR-17
>   08.30.41.453267 AM"

I tried to set the date time  in `DMY` on Postgres but it did not work. I can input the data if I convert it to `YMD` format (i.e. I have to change numerous fields and almost 50 TB of data)

can someone please help me on this.

```
badmin=# copy downloaded_file from '/export/home/dbadmin/postgresql/TESTPGDB/scripts/FACTSET_IDS_2_V1.DOWNLOADED_FILE.csv' 
   with delimiter ','; 
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp:
"20-MAR-17 08.30.41.453267 AM" CONTEXT:  COPY downloaded_file, line 1,
column DOWNLOAD_TIME: "20-MAR-17 08.30.41.453267 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your main table has following columns and datatypes.

```
\d downloaded_file
 Column |            Type
--------+----------------------------
 id     | integer
 txt    | text
 tstamp | timestamp without time zone
```

Now, rather than copying directly into the table, create a temporary table with the same columns but with all text datatypes.

```
create temporary  table downloaded_file_tmp ( id text, txt text, tstamp text);
```

Now, copy the contents of the file into this temp table.

The file looks like this.

```
$cat f.csv
1,'TEXT1','20-MAR-17 08.30.41.453267 AM'
```

Copying from file to temp table.

```
\copy downloaded_file_tmp from 'f.csv' with delimiter ',' CSV;
```

Copying from temp table to main table.

```
INSERT INTO downloaded_file 
            (id, 
             txt, 
             tstamp) 
SELECT id :: INT, 
       txt, 
       TO_TIMESTAMP('20-MAR-17 08.30.41.453267 AM', 'dd-mon-yy hh.mi.ss.US AM') 
FROM   downloaded_file_tmp;
```

Notice the [format specifier](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) `US` which represents  microsecond (000000-999999)

```
knayak=# select * from downloaded_file;
 id |   txt   |           tstamp
----+---------+----------------------------
  1 | 'TEXT1' | 2017-03-20 08:30:41.453267
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce we already tried this but we have 8000 tables basically we want to retire the oracle database and take the backup of data in CSV files and in future if needed we can import into open source database strange requirement i know but its like that. Its too much of duplicate effort so just want to know is there any other way by which we can directly import the data ? even without typecasting the oracle columns?